# grep to find unique values using a wildcard

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to find all the unique Cookie ID values in a large folder of text files I downloaded from S3 to see how many duplicates there are.

Here is a sample of how the data looks, but the number in quotes will vary.

```
"user_attributes":{"1234567890":"<Cookie ID>",
```

I am trying to use grep to find the unique Cookie ID values and print them to a file.

```
cat cookieid.txt | grep "\"*\":\"<Cookie ID>" > output.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: `grep` uses regular expressions, not wildcards.

Comment: The name stands for *Global Regular Expression Print*.

Comment: Please add your desired output of `grep` for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a wildcard with `grep`, you have to use a regular expression. `.*` is the regexp that matches anything, analogous to the `*` wildcard.

And you need to put the output redirection at the end of the pipeline. You're sending the `grep` output to the file, and nothing is being piped to `sort` and `uniq`.

```
grep '".*":"<Cookie ID>' cookieid.txt | sort | uniq -c > output.txt
```